# COVID19 data statistical adjustment for SIR model and estimation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, parameter-estimation, biology

All of us are coping with the current COVID19 crisis. I hope that all of you stay safe and that this situation will end as soon as possible.

For this sad situation and for my unstoppable curiosity, I've started to read something about the SIR model. The variables of such model are $s$ (the fraction of people susceptible to infection), $y$ (the fraction of infected people) and $r$ (the fraction of recovered people + the sad statistics of deaths). The model reads as:

$$\begin{cases}
\dot{s} = -\beta s y\\
\dot{y} = \beta sy - \gamma y\\
\dot{r} = \gamma y
\end{cases},$$

where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are positive parameters. One strong hypothesis of this model is that the population size is constant over time (deaths are assumed to be recovered, births are neglected since, hopefully, they will be the part of the population which for sure will be protected from the disease).
The initial conditions are set such that $s(0)+y(0)+r(0) = 1$ and $s(0) \geq 0$, $y(0) \geq 0$ and $r(0) \geq 0$. Under this assumption, it can be proven that $s(t)+y(t)+r(t) = 1 ~\forall t > 0$.

The news often talk about the coefficient:

$$R_0 = \frac{\beta}{\gamma},$$

which rules the behavior of the system (for $R_0 < 1$ the disease will be wiped out, for $R_0 > 1$ it will spread out).

The same news also talk about the estimation of such parameter. Well, given the time series of $s$, $y$ and $r$, it is rather easy to estimate the parameters $\beta$ and $\gamma$, and hence $R_0$.
My main concern is about the time series. For each country we know the daily count of infected people (let's say $Y(t)$), of recovered (or dead) people (let's say $R(t)$).

Anyway, there are several infected people which are not recorded (let's say $Y'(t)$), and many of them get recovered without knowing that they have been infected (let's say $R'(t)$)! Moreover, day after day, the number of tests on people is increasing.

If we indicate with $N$ the (constant) size of population, we get that:

$$y(t) = \frac{Y(t) + Y'(t)}{N}, r(t) = \frac{R(t) + R'(t)}{N} ~\text{and}~ s(t) = 1-y(t)-r(t).$$

Here is the question(s). How can we perform the estimation of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ if we don't know the unobserved variables $Y'(t)$ and $R'(t)$? How do the experts of the field estimate $\beta$ and $\gamma$ even though the available data are not complete? Do they use some data adjustment?

Comment: As discussed [here](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/a-comic-strip-tour-of-the-wild-world-of-pandemic-modeling/), some data sources have smaller $R^\prime,\,Y^\prime$ than others. The most precise sources are certain nations, or cruises. On the right assumptions, you can give even imprecise sources (rather wide) error bars. Combining several estimates allows you to get narrower ones, with a lot of parameter estimation theory. But most of the details you want would come from epidemiologists, not mathematicians.

Comment: Please note that R naught is the initial reproduction rate. This later evolves over time, hopefully decreasing through isolation and herd immunity. I believe the term 'effective reproduction rate or number' is used for that time dependent parameter.

Comment: More on-topic: The basic SIR model is a nice introduction, but too simple for any real-world applications. More realistic models like SEIRD or SEILHRD adding more detailed phases of exposure and light and heavy symptoms of illness do not fit well automatically. Manual fit in my limited experiments requires to reduce the reference population size to 1/100 to 1/1000 of the actual population to get non-ridiculous results.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Do you mean $R_0$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Well, I will start reading about SEIRD and SEILHRD models. Anyway, my question on data is still unsolved. Indeed, even though we have more complex models, the data must still be processed in order to account for the the non-observed quantities.

Comment: You are unlikely to find the second. SIR-X exists, there was a question about this previously here, where automated fitting did not work/did produce ridiculous results as the paper it was from did not have details on how the case numbers were translated into population percentages.

Comment: As for the data clean up, you probably would need source data as [this paper](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/Infekt/EpidBull/Archiv/2020/Ausgaben/17_20_SARS-CoV2_vorab.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) has, backdating the reported cases to the reported onset of serious disease, showing that in Germany the peak in these onsets was around march 16 meaning infections peaked in the first week of march. It is also noted that the data is not incompatible with a constant number of new cases, the initial peak produced by the initial ramp-up of test numbers.

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_reproduction_number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have accurate numbers for $R$ and $Y$ in any large population.  Most of the deaths may be recorded (although there may be a substantial number of deaths that are not attributed to Covid-19 because the symptoms are not typical), but large numbers of people have very mild symptoms, going from $S$ to $Y$ and into $R$ without ever being tested.

From the point of view of getting accurate statistics, it would be desirable to take a random sample of the population and test them at frequent intervals. But as far as I know this has not been done anywhere.

Of course there are all sorts of complications.  Rather than a homogeneous population, there are lots of subpopulations that have different parameters, and varying amounts of interactions between them.
For example, residents of long-term care homes are an important subpopulation, the one that's producing a very large fraction of the deaths.

So if $s_j, i_j, r_j$ are the numbers of susceptible, infective and removed in subpopulation $j$, you should have
$$ \eqalign{ \dot{s}_j &= -\sum_k \beta_{jk} s_j i_k\cr
             \dot{i}_j &= \sum_k \beta_{jk} s_j i_k - \gamma_j i_j\cr
             \dot{r}_j &= \gamma_j i_j\cr} $$

However, increasing the number of subpopulations increases the number of parameters, making parameter estimation even more of a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will start reading about multipopulation SIR. Anyway, my question on data is still unsolved. Indeed, even though we have more complex models, the data must still be processed in order to account for the the non-observed quantities.